# SSIS Date Conversion keeps throwing errors String->DBDATE

Tags: sql-server, date, ssis, type-conversion, date-conversion

I'm currently working on a SSIS project where I import from a .csv file, which contains, amongst others, dates. The dates are formatted as yyyy-mm-dd, and also read in as such on the file connection preview. I then do a data conversion where I assign a new column to use the data as DBDATE type. The original data is in WSTR (Unicode String) with size 10. I then get the following errors on my data conversion:

```
Error: 0xC02020C5 at Data Flow Task, Data Conversion [2]: Data conversion failed while converting column "Leverdatum" (25) to column "NewLeverdatum" (8).  The conversion returned status value 2 and status text "The value could not be converted because of a potential loss of data.".

Error: 0xC0209029 at Data Flow Task, Data Conversion [2]: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_INDUCEDTRANSFORMFAILUREONERROR.  The "Data Conversion.Outputs[Data Conversion Output].Columns[NewLeverdatum]" failed because error code 0xC020907F occurred, and the error row disposition on "Data Conversion.Outputs[Data Conversion Output].Columns[NewLeverdatum]" specifies failure on error. An error occurred on the specified object of the specified component.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information about the failure.

Error: 0xC0047022 at Data Flow Task, SSIS.Pipeline: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_PROCESSINPUTFAILED.  The ProcessInput method on component "Data Conversion" (2) failed with error code 0xC0209029 while processing input "Data Conversion Input" (3). The identified component returned an error from the ProcessInput method. The error is specific to the component, but the error is fatal and will cause the Data Flow task to stop running.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information about the failure.
```

The project is in locale English(US). I have also tried using the local date format on my machine, which is dd-mm-yyyy. Please advise what I can do to import this column as a date.

I have tried using a Derived Column instead of Data Conversion and I have also tried setting the type of the column to DBDATE directly.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: Currently it is okay to import the data as a task, since the data will be exported to Excel and this will recognize the date in text form. Would still like an answer if anyone has one

Answer (score 1):

`DT_DBDATE` format is expecting `yyyy-mm-dd`

I believe your new column is `NewLeverdatum` and your old `DT_WSTR` column is `Leverdatum`

Based on the error

> Error: 0xC02020C5 at Data Flow Task, Data Conversion [2]: Data
>   conversion failed while converting column "Leverdatum" (25) to column
>   "NewLeverdatum" (8).  The conversion returned status value 2 and
>   status text "The value could not be converted because of a potential
>   loss of data.".

it failed because `DT_DBDATE` will result to 10 character date with dash -

Change your `Leverdatum` column to allow `len = 10`

Comment: Hi Metal, thanks for taking the time to answer. I have set the OutputColumnWidth to 10 if this is what you mean. I use Microsoft Visual Studio SSDT. See the settings here: https://imgur.com/KdOsvYr

Comment: how about the newlèverdatum?

Comment: Right here: https://imgur.com/zi5c27k
There are no actions before the flat file source.

Comment: do you have same data?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: your input date, from csv

Comment: The data looks like this:
2019-10-25;4444;Belki NV;4699;NL-BIO-01;466428;272,000;2019-10-24;2019-10-26;3A;4444

Comment: change newleverdarum to dt_wstr

Comment: That defeats the purpose of the conversion, since Leverdatum is already a WSTR. I need to get this as a date.